# Where is Magento registration form data stored?

Tags: magento

Where is Magento registration form data stored? In which database table(s)?

Answer (score 3):

to find out query used to get the customer data do this, and this is probably EAV structure where all data is kept:

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getSelect();?>
```

or this

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('customerid')->getSelect();?>
```

and to find out what fields are available on default collection or load:

```
<?php print_r(Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getFirstItem()->getData());?>
```

or this

```
<?php print_r(Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('customerid')->getData());?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer is correct for accessing data through the Magento framework. To answer your question literally, the following tables store the basic customer data:

```
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_entp (customer%)       |
+----------------------------------+
| customer_address_entity          |
| customer_address_entity_datetime |
| customer_address_entity_decimal  |
| customer_address_entity_int      |
| customer_address_entity_text     |
| customer_address_entity_varchar  |
| customer_entity                  |
| customer_entity_datetime         |
| customer_entity_decimal          |
| customer_entity_int              |
| customer_entity_text             |
| customer_entity_varchar          |
+----------------------------------+
```